# How much can we tell about $\det(X)$ if we know $\det(I + X)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

1. What can we tell about $\det(X)$ if we know $\det(I + X)$? Will it
   give some kind of bound for $\det(X)$?
2. In general, if we know the determinant of matrix $A + X$, where $A$ is a constant matrix, how much can we say about $\det(X)$?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: This is essentially what you ask: "Let $p(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$.  I know the value of $p(t)$ for some $t\in\mathbb{C}$.  What do we know about $p(0)$?"  The answer is ***nothing***.  For any $t\neq 0$ and any possible value of $p(t)$, $p(0)$ can take any value, provided that $n>1$.

Comment: @Batominovski,  thank you for the reply. How is det(A + X), det(X) related to the polynomial of p(t) , p(0) in your answer ?

Comment: @david  Take $p(x):=\det(x\,I-X)$ (i.e., the characteristic polynomial of $X$), and you will see.

Comment: @david The situation is rather specific to the case where the shift is by a multiple of $I$. In this case the function $p(\lambda)=\operatorname{det}(A+\lambda I)$ is a polynomial. In general it can be *any* monic polynomial of degree $n$ (there is a so-called "companion matrix" for any monic polynomial, which has that polynomial as its characteristic polynomial). You're saying that you know $p(1)$ and want to know $p(0)$, but this cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues $$\det({\bf A}) =  \prod_k \lambda_k({\bf A})$$

Then it is well known that all eigenvalues increase by 1 if adding $\bf I$ to any matrix:

$$\det({\bf A+I}) =  \prod_k (\lambda_k({\bf A})+1)$$

Maybe you can rewrite this product into something you are comfortable working with. I do not think this extends in any nice way to adding $\bf X\neq I$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}$ be the set of eigenvalues of $X$. Then the set of eigevalues of $I+X$ is $\{1+\lambda_1,\dots,1+\lambda_n\}$. Determinant of any matrix $X$ is equal to product of all eigenvalues of $X$, thus
\begin{align}
\det(X) = \prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i &&\det(I+X) = \prod_{i=1}^n(1+\lambda_i) \tag{1}
\end{align}
From (1) it is clear that (in general) nothing can be said about $\det(I+X)$.

If all eigenvalues of $X$ are real and positive (i.e. $X$ is positive definite), then $\det(I+X) > \det(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

If we are given an invertible matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and the following determinant

$$\beta := \det (X + \alpha 1_n 1_n^T)$$

then

$$\beta = \det (X + \alpha 1_n 1_n^T) = \det (X) \cdot \underbrace{\det (I_n + \alpha X^{-1} 1_n 1_n^T)}_{= 1 + \alpha 1_n^T X^{-1} 1_n} = (1 + \alpha 1_n^T X^{-1} 1_n) \cdot \det (X)$$

where we used [Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity). Thus,

$$\det (X) = \frac{\beta}{1 + \alpha 1_n^T X^{-1} 1_n}$$

Comment: The OP wants $\det(X+I)$, not $\det(X+1_n1_n^T)$.

Comment: @egreg Please read the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: “In general…” doesn't mean “for a carefully selected case”. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg The OP wrote "**constant** matrix". The case is not carefully selected, it's what he asked for.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, thank you for the reply. I am not familiar with the symbol you used. What is a1n, 1Tn in your expression ?

Comment: @david If you want an $n \times n$ constant matrix where all $n^2$ entries are $\alpha$, then use $\alpha 1_n 1_n^T$, where $1_n$ is the $n$-dimensional column vector of ones, and $1_n 1_n^T$ is the $n \times n$ matrix of ones.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing** To document that "nothing if $d>1$" where $d$ is the dimension is the answer (as said above) :

Claim: For any $\lambda\in \mathbb R$ there exists a matrix $X$ such that $\det X  = \lambda$, while $\det(I+X)=0$.

As a corollary (take $\lambda = \pm n\in\mathbb N$ in the first claim),

Corollary: there exists a sequence $X_n$ such that $\det X_n \to \pm \infty$ while $\det(I+X_n)=0$.

This tells you that nothing general can be said.

Proof. If $d$ is odd take $X$ to be be diagonal matrix with $X_{11}=\lambda$ and $X_{kk}=1$ for $2\leq k\leq d-1$ and $X_{dd}=-1$.  If $d$ is even and greater or equal to $4$, $X_{kk}=1$ for $2\leq k\leq d-2$ and $X_{d-1,d-1}= X_{dd}=-1$. if$d=2$, take $X=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & \lambda \\ -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

**Something**

On the other hand, it could be that you meant something else than what you asked. For example, what is true is [Hadamard's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380564/bound-on-the-difference-of-two-determinants):
$$
\| \det(A+X) -\det(A) \| \leq C(d) \|X\| \max(\|A+X\|^{d-1},\|A\|^{d-1})
$$