# Relative bound of determinant of perturbed matrix

Tags: matrices, reference-request, determinant

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ real-symmetric matrices. We think of $B$ as a small perturbation of $A$.

I am looking for a bound on
$$
\frac{\det(A + B) - \det A}{\det A}.
$$
In particular one that is optimal in $n$.

A bound of the form $(1 + \varepsilon)^n$ is shown in
[Ilse C. F. Ipsen and Rizwana Rehman, "Perturbation Bounds for Determinants and Characteristic Polynomials", SIAM J. MATRIX ANAL. APPL. Vol. 30, No. 2, pp. 762–776, https://doi.org/10.1137/070704770]. There the following is proved (Cor. 2.14):
$$
\left\vert \frac{\det(A + B) - \det A}{\det A} \right\vert 
\leq \left(1 + \left\Vert A^{-1} \right\Vert \Vert B\Vert \right)^n - 1,
$$
where $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ denotes the operator norm. (See also [Bound on the difference of two determinants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380564/bound-on-the-difference-of-two-determinants). )

Can one do better than a bound of the form $(1+\varepsilon)^n$?

#### Additional comments

By computing the derivative of $\log \det(A + tB)$ we get that
$$
\log \det(A + B) - \log \det A = \mathrm{tr}[(A + t_0 B)^{-1}B]
$$
for some $0 < t_0 < 1$. Thus, if one could get a good bound on
$\exp(\mathrm{tr}[(A + t_0 B)^{-1}B]) - 1$
we would be done. I don't see any good way of doing this.

If it is of any help, the specific matrices I'm looking at also satisfy the following:

- $|\det A|, |\det(A + B)|\leq 1 + \varepsilon$ for some small $\varepsilon$
- $A_{ij} \geq 0$
- $A$ is block-diagonal