# Upper bound for determinant of square matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, trace, upper-lower-bounds

Let $A \in \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ be a non-Hermitian matrix whose entries are denoted by $a_{i,j}$.

1. What is the best upper bound that we have for $\det (A)$  in term of $\mbox{trace}(A)$?
2. Does the following inequality hold for any complex matrix $A$?

$$\det(A) \leq \bigg(\frac{\mbox{trace}}{n}\bigg)^n$$

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202248/upper-bound-on-determinant-of-matrix-in-terms-of-trace

Comment: You need to give more information about what you are looking for, the best upper bound is $\det A$, of course. There is Hadamard's inequality.

Comment: @Dude in your link the upper bound holds for A is Hermitian or symmetric .but I didi' t assume that?

Comment: if $\det(A) \leq \bigg(\frac{Trace(A)}{n}\bigg)^n$ was true for any complex matrix then $\text{GM}\leq \text{AM}$ would hold for any selection of $x_i \in \mathbb C$ which of course is wrong.  $\text{GM}\leq \text{AM}$ requires $x_i\geq 0$ for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best upper bound is $+\infty$. Consider the companion matrix
$$
C=\pmatrix{0&&&&d\\
1&\ddots&&&0\\
&\ddots&\ddots&&\vdots\\
&&\ddots&0&0\\
&&&1&t}.
$$
Then $\operatorname{tr}(C)=t$ and $\det(C)=(-1)^{n-1}d$. Since $d$ and $t$ do not depend on each other, $|\det(C)|$ can assume any nonnegative real value, given $\operatorname{tr}(C)$.

Comment: I ask whether this inequality holds for any complex matrix $$\det(A) \leq \bigg(\frac{Trace(A)}{n}\bigg)^n$$

Comment: @Abdo Of course it doesn't hold. Just pick a $d$ that is large enough in the counterexample above. If you want an inequality of the $AM\ge GM$ type, you need $A$ to have a nonnegative spectrum.

Comment: do you know  other upper bound for the complex matrix?

Comment: @Abdo As copper.hat has pointed out in a comment under your question, we have Hadamard's inequality $|\det(A)|\le\prod_{j=1}^n\|a_{\ast j}\|_2$, which is a simple consequence of QR factorisation.

Comment: in Wikipedia article said that Hadamard's inequality holds if and only if the columns vectors of $A$ are orthogonal is that true?

Comment: @Abdo Yes and this also follows from QR factorisation.

Comment: if we assume that A is a complex square matrix which also diagonalizable and $detA \in \mathbb{R}$, in this case, does the inequality of the trace(the first one) holds ?

Comment: @Abdo No. Consider $A=\pmatrix{0&-a\\ a&0}$ with $a>0$ for instance. It is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$ because its two eigenvalues $\pm i$ are different. Its trace is zero, but $\det(A)=a^2$ is unbounded.

Comment: actually I am looking for and an upper for the matrix of a linear transformation $m_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha x$ where the basis $S={ \zeta, \zeta^{2}, ....., \zeta^{p-1}}$ consist of the p-the root of unity, and $p$ is prime so obviously, the matrix representation $[m_{\alpha}]$ is compilex but it is hard to prove that it is Hermitian or orthogonal  , so do you know any upper which help here ?